# Finding the lowest/highest number in an array using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

For my web development class, I have the following assignment:

Before your boss allows adjustable thermostats in the office suite, he must be convinced that major temperature variations occur in different officers and within each office on different days. You're to write a program that allows each employee to enter the temperature at noon on each of five days and displays the highest, lowest, and average (mean) temperatures. Use a For loop to take the five readings. (*Hint*: Initialize the highest and lowest temperature variable to the first temperature that's read, and then compare other temperatures to see whether they're lower or higher.) Use the parseFloat() method to convert your temperature input to a decimal number and display the average to one decimal place.

How can I find the average temperature?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var high; // highest temperature
    var low; // lowest temperature
    var avg; // average temperature

    var temperatures = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        high = temperatures[0];
        low = temperatures[0];

        temperatures.push(parseFloat(prompt("Enter the temperature for day " + (i+1))));

        if (high < temperatures[i]) {
            high = temperatures[i]; }
        if (low > temperatures[i]) {
            low = temperatures[i]; }

    }

    document.write("The highest temperature is " + high + ".<br>");
    document.write("The lowest temperature was " + low + ".<br>");
    document.write("The average temperature was " + avg + ".");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A couple of points to get you started. 1) the question states `Use a For loop to take the five readings`, but you're using separate variables. This could be achieved in a loop. Do you know how? 2) You're overwriting `temp1` in `alltemp` with `high` and then `low`, both of which are `undefined`. Whereas you want to do the opposite. Set `high` and `low` to equal `alltemp[0]`.

Comment: @fubar Thanks for your help! I was able to get the loop to return the correct high and low temperatures. However, I don't know how I can get rid of the temp1, temp2, temp3, etc. variables and still make it work.

Comment: have a look at the answer I've posted below. It's not a complete solution, but it will get you started. Then if you edit your question with your updated code, I can try to help further.

Comment: @fubar Updated...now, without all those variables, I don't know what to do to find the average temperature.

Comment: I've responded with an updated answer to hopefully step you through the thought process. Let me know your questions, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

@Emily, here's something to get you started with using a `for` loop to collect the user input.

```
var temperatures = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var temperature = prompt('Enter temperature for day ' + i);
    // Parse input and add it to the temperatures array
}
```

**Step 2**

Awesome, so you now have an array of 5 temperatures called `temperatures`. In the example below, I've split the line for capturing and pushing the value into two separate statements for readability. As follows:

```
var temperature = prompt('Enter the temperature for day ' + (i + 1));
temperatures.push(parseFloat(temperature));
```

Another minor change that you need to make is that you're assigning `high` and `low` values inside the loop, but before any values have been pushed to the `temperatures` array, so we'll need to look at that.

But first, finding the average temperature. So average, as you already know, is the sum of all values, divided by the number of values. On each iteration of our loop, we're getting the next temperature value. So we could use the loop to add all of those values together. As follows:

```
var temperatures = [];
var total = 0;
var high;
var low;
var avg;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Capture, parse and append temperature to temperatures array
    var temperature = prompt('Enter the temperature for day ' + (i + 1));
    temperatures.push(parseFloat(temperature));

    // Increment total by new temperature value
    total += temperature;
}
```

But what about the `high` and `low` temperatures? If we take the code from your latest question update, on every iteration of the loop, `high` and `low` will be reset to the first temperature, and then you'll compare it to the current temperature in the loop. This won't work.

What we could do however, is to set `high` and `low` to very low and very high values, so that any temperature entered by the user would always be higher or lower. For example:

```
var high = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var low = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

Then on each iteration of the loop, we take the code you've already written to compare the current temperature against the previous `high` and `low` values. As follows:

```
var temperatures = [];
var total = 0;
var high = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var low = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var avg;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Capture, parse and append temperature to temperatures array
    var temperature = prompt('Enter the temperature for day ' + (i + 1));
    temperatures.push(parseFloat(temperature));

    // Increment total by new temperature value
    total += temperature;

    // Compare high and low temperatures
    if (high < temperature) high = temperature;
    if (low > temperature) low = temperature;
}
```

And finally, how do you calculate the average?

```
// Calculate average temperature
avg = total / temperatures.length;
```

**Step 3**

This code could be improved further, if you're interested. But it may be beyond the scope of this question.

If you would like to improve it, take a look at `Math.min()`, `Math.max()`, and `apply()`. I'm happy to post some more code to show how these can be used for getting the high and low temperatures, as well as `Array.prototype.reduce` for calculating the average.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting values in alltemp to the high or the low, not the other way around. Here's a fiddle that shows you how you can do this (since you have to use a for loop, but there are cleaner ways): https://jsfiddle.net/vtbahu3v/

```
var nums = [2, 55, 3, 87, 4, 23],
    high = low = nums[0];

for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    high = Math.max(high, nums[i]);
  low = Math.min(low, nums[i]);
}

alert("High is " + high);
alert("Low is " + low);
```

Comment: **danger danger will robinson** `low` is defined globally here. Be careful with those shortcuts you're taking!